# vsCode c++ minGW no such file or directory error

Tags: c++

I'm first time learning c++ and have followed the guide on https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw but I still cannot successfully compile and run a basic program. Here are my configurations, launch and tasks files.
The only issue I think could be occurring is that I have the code in my E: drive. Although I don't think this should be an issue. Any and all help appreciated.

Configurations:

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE",
            "_UNICODE"
        ],
        "compilerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe",
        "cStandard": "c11",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
    }
],
"version": 4
}
```

Launch:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [

    {
        "name": "(gdb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/helloworld.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": true,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": true,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Tasks:

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "build hello world",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "gcc",
        "args": [
            "-g",
            "-o",
            "helloworld",
            ".vscode"
            "helloworld.cpp"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    }
]
}
```

Output is:

```
> Executing task: gcc -g -o helloworld .vscode helloworld.cpp <
gcc.exe: error: helloworld.cpp: No such file or directory
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 1
Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

Comment: Where is `MinGW` installed? Have you installed it? I suspect that is the problem. If you install it on its own, it will generally install to `C:\MinGW` with the important dirs being `C:\MinGW\bin`. If you have installed it with Code::Block, or similar, then it is probably installed below that program directory in `Program Files\Code::Blocks\MinGW`, etc.. Once installed, it is just a matter of telling VS where it lives.

Comment: By the looks of the error, VS knows MinGW is installed and finds `gcc.exe`. The problem being it can't find `helloworld.cpp` -- that's your no such file or directory. I always add the path to `MinGW\bin` to my path. That way I can just open a Command Prompt, change to the directory with my source file, and then `g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Ofast -o nameforexe mysource.cpp`  That way I eliminate any of VS settings throwing things off as a test.

Comment: Yeah I have MinGW installed at C:/MinGW and have added it to my path. I think what you said about g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Ofast -o nameforexe mysource.cpp may have worked, it created a binary file. Now how would I go about running this? Thanks a heap

Comment: Nevermind, I just executed it from command prompt and it worked perfectly. Thank you a lot, is there a way this could be implemented into vsCode? Or should I just continue to use the command prompt?

Comment: Yes, you just did basically. The problem with VS projects, is all the setup, paths, hacking json files, etc.. have nothing to do with programming, they have to do with "How do I use VS?". It can be just as frustrating to make friends with VS as it is to learn to program. You did on the command line exactly what VS is supposed to make it easier to do (cough...) Generally in VS, it is a Right-click the project, choose properties and then set as needed in the 40 dialogs of stuff. Where the command prompt makes things so simple -- you don't need a project, you just compile what you need a move on.

Comment: Seriously, when I have to fight with VS, I usually start with a short tutorial, e.g. [Get started with Visual Studio 2017](https://tutorials.visualstudio.com/vs-get-started/creating-and-running) and go from there. MS has fairly good documentation to address the "How do I do 'X'?" on VS -- the only problem is finding them. Go though a few of their tutorials and get comfortable with the project options in VS. Things will start making sense quickly -- it's just a matter of experience.

Comment: David C. Rankin@ colon is not a valid character for Windows directory name

Comment: Thanks a lot David, I'll continue to use command prompt for now, until I need to start debugging larger projects. By then I should have some solid experience with both c++ and VS. Cheers again!